# Change background on click of Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a penalty shooting game using JavaScript. I have given two shoot options and it will randomly select one while chicking the button. If the shoot is 1 the background color of the span tag changes to green else it should change to red. I got stuck in changing the color of the tag.

```js
var ButtonClick = () => {
  var shoot = score[Math.floor(Math.random() * score.length)];
  if (turn === 1) {
    team1.shoot.push(shoot);
    team1.total = calculateTotal(team1.shoot);
  } else {
    team2.shoot.push(shoot);
    team2.total = calculateTotal(team2.shoot);
  }
  updateButtonText();
  updateShoot();
}

var updateShoot = () => {
  var teamOne = document.getElementById("team-1-round-shoot").children;
  var teamTwo = document.getElementById("team-2-round-shoot").children;
  team1.shoot.forEach((shoot, index) => {
    shoot === 1 ? teamOne[index].style.background = "green" : teamOne[index].style.background = "red";
  })
  team2.shoot.forEach((shoot, index) => {
    shoot === 1 ? teamTwo[index].style.background = "green" :   teamTwo[index].style.background = "red";
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col container">
    <img class="img" src="/assets/Anguilla.png" alt="anguilla">
    <span class="name" id="team-1-name"></span>
    <div class="row" id="team-1-round-shoot">
      <span class="round"></span>
      <span class="round"></span>
      <span class="round"></span>
      <span class="round"></span>
      <span class="round"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col container">
    <img class="img" src="/assets/Armenia.png" alt="armenia">
    <span class="name" id="team-2-name"></span>
    <div class="row" id="team-2-round-shoot">
      <span class="round"></span>
      <span class="round"></span>
      <span class="round"></span>
      <span class="round"></span>
      <span class="round"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of `style.background-color`  use `style.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. The below code needs to change on both lines.

```
teamTwo[index].style.background - color = "red"
```

to

```
 teamTwo[index].style.background = "red"
```

or

```
teamTwo[index].style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

Comment: Although you are correct ... please don't answer typo caused problems ! Solve them by simply commenting ..